# Is it possible to create a free and referable website?

Tags: w3c

I wanted to know if it is possible to create a free website that can be referenced on search engines (Google, bing, Yahoo etc.)?

I ask this because I have a friend who asked me to create him an online CV and that it be referenced on the internet. And which therefore has no monetization objective.

The problem is that I have never migrated an online site and that all the sites I have worked on pay their servers.

That's why I'm asking my question here. Is this possible, or is it better that I advise my friend to make his site on wix.

Answer (score -1):

[Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) is probably the "go to" solution for free, reliable, static website hosting.

Comment: Github page? I have already created a site on it, but it doesn t show up on Google when I type the exact address. Is there a way to get it referenced?